# sharepoint 2013 valid domain account

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to make a new farm but always get this error:
[image]

I also tried to make something like [this](http://sharepointjim.com/2014/09/20/the-username-is-invalid-the-account-must-be-a-valid-domain-account-sharepoint-2013-setup-error/)

but it does not work [image]

How to solve this problem? What is wrong with the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have AD domain in your environment? 
You should try to specify username with domain name, like "domain\test". In case you are using local user account, try "localhost\test" instead.
Anyway, the user which you try to specify **must** already exist!